# Unable to install dask[complete]

Tags: python, dask

I am trying to install dask[complete] via pip on Mac OSX, but I am always getting no matches found: dask[complete]. What is the best way to install dask[complete] library on Mac OSX?

```
pip install dask[complete]
zsh: no matches found: dask[complete]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some terminals handle this differently.  I recommend placing `"dask[complete]"` in quotes:

```
pip install "dask[complete]"
```

Answer (score 1):

or with requirements.txt

```
awscli==1.16.69
botocore=1.13.0
boto3==1.9.79
dask[complete]
```

Comment: ```dask[complete]``` is enough